# SQL cyrillic table name

Tags: mysql, sql, cyrillic

How to CREATE a table with Cyrillic name and SELECT rows from that table in SQL? Also, how to make a column that accepts Cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5686d/1

```
CREATE TABLE таб1 (id int, name varchar(30)) CHARSET=utf8;
```